# Grouping with MongoDB while preserving all keys and values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to run a query with MongoDB, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have two scrapers collecting data at the same time from different API's and inserting them in the same collection in different documents. If I have the following documents in my collection:

```
{
'scraper': 1,
'time': 24,
'number: 500
}

{
'scraper': 2,
'time': 24,
'number: 600
}

{
'scraper': 1,
'time': 12,
'number: 700
} 

{
'scraper': 2,
'time': 12,
'number: 800
}
```

After the query, I want to compare the data (and thus group) based on time, but keep the scraper id's and numbers of both documents together.

```
{
'time': 24,
'data':[
    {'scraper':1, 'number:500},
    {'scraper':2, 'number':600}]
}

{
'time': 12,
'data':[
    {'scraper':1, 'number:700},
    {'scraper':2, 'number':800}]
}
```

I would link my attempt, but I am way too far off. I think I need to use .aggregate and group somehow, but I can't seem to figure out how to preserve the data from both documents and rearrange it.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with your aggregate groups, $addToSet will keep the original unique values, or you can use $push if you want to preserve the duplicates:

addToSet:

```
db.groups.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: '$time', data: {$addToSet: {scraper: '$scraper', number: '$number' }}}}
])
```

push:

```
db.groups.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: '$time', data: {$push: {scraper: '$scraper', number: '$number' }}}}
])
```

(both will give the same result with the data set you've provided)

If maintaining the field name, 'time' instead of _id is important to you, you can add an additional project phase.

```
db.groups.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: '$time', data: {$push: {scraper: '$scraper', number: '$number' }}}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, time: '$_id', data: 1}}
])
```